# Pinescript: is it possible to create a condition based on the color?

Tags: pine-script

I want to make an indicator that changes color when another indicator changes color. Is there a way to do this in pine script?

The initial indicator is closed source. So I have no access to the code.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You can't share data between indicators.

Comment: Actually you can. You can build an indicator on top of another indicator. So you can access the initial one. E.g. you can use EMA on a custom indicator, this is accessing the data of it. I also build some on my own. So your statement is not true.